# c++ return to a different result

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, return-value, greedy

I found that the parameter I returned is different in the outer function when it's called than where it was in the local function. I set some printing out in each section of the code but still have no idea why the parameter i is not returned:

```
int assign_cookie(vector<int>& g, vector<int>& s){  

if(s.size()==0 || g.size()==0){
        cout << "size = 0, returning 0" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

cout << "s.size() = " << s.size() << endl;
cout << "g.size() = " << g.size() << endl;

sort(g.begin(), g.end());
sort(s.begin(), s.end());

unsigned int i, j = 0;
while(i<g.size() && j<s.size()){
    if(g[i]<=s[j]) i++;
    j++;
}
cout << "(assign_cookie) i = " << i << endl;
return i; 

}
```

when I called it in the main function as follows:

```
int main(){

int g[] = {1,2,3};
int s[] = {1,1};

vector<int> vg (g, g+3);
vector<int> vs (s, s+2);

int result = assign_cookie(vg,vs);
cout << "result = " << result << endl;
}
```

I got results as follows:

```
s.size() = 2
g.size() = 3
(assign_cookie) i = 1
(main) result = 0
```

I was very confused with the result. Anyone has an idea what's going on?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour, because here

```
unsigned int i,j=0;
```

you only initialize `j` but not `i` and then you use `i` as index in `g[i]` without ever assigning it a meaningful value. Hence it is UB and anything can happen. Actually this is an interesting case of UB, as when you do

```
unsigned int i,j=0;
std::cout << "i = " << i << "\n";
```

it still prints

```
i = 0
(assign_cookie) i = 1
result = 0
```

[see also here](http://ideone.com/bXgmZI). Even if the compiler seems to initialize `i` to `0` it still realizes that there is UB and takes the freedom to produce garbage output.